# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS not working, 403 forbidden message in client

Tags: http, https, web-config, iis-10

I am running Drupal 8.7.7 on IIS 10, with Plesk 17.8.11

From the code in web.config I would expect an automatic reroute from http://www.focusonlineperformance.nl to https://www.focusonlineperformance.nl

But instead, I get a 403 forbidden message on Chrome.

I have tried  `<match url=".*" />`
I have tried `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />`

I have the following script in web.config:

```
<rule name="Plesk. SSL redirect for #6" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" 
stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_IS_SITEPREVIEW}" pattern="1" 
negate="true" />
 </conditions>
  <serverVariables />
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use FRT first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @Erwin  if your issue is resolved I request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue in the future.thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below URL rewrite rule:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

make sure you configure https binding for the site and with the right certificate.

and uncheck "Require SSL" by following below steps:

- Open iis manager. select your site.
- Double click on SSL setting feature from the middle pane:

[image]

- Uncheck the require SSL and click on apply.

[image]

Comment: Great!!! That did the trick. Although what's the logic of unchecking require SSL for a SSL site ? And do I need the HTTP type bindings in this setup? Thanks again!

Comment: If you have it set to Require, then it will require client authentication and if you don't specify a client certificate, it will give you the access denied. If you set it to ignore or accept, it will not be a fatal error if you don't specify client certificate.

Comment: @Erwin if your issue is resolved I request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue in the future.thank you for understanding.

Comment: still working in 2023, worked for me